# Conversion to native javascript returns destructuring error

Tags: javascript, zxing

The following script is a conversion of a TypeScript to native Javascript so that it may run inline.
It is subordinated to the zxing library loaded via importmaps

```
    <script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    [...]
    "@zxing/library": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@zxing/library@0.19.1/esm/index.js",
    "ts-custom-error": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:ts-custom-error@3.2.0/dist/custom-error.js",
    [...]
}
```

It returns the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target`
for a line that indicates:
`url: "http://localhost:3000/articlephotos/barcode_section_update",`

One additional edit was made to convert a jQuery function to run independantly of jQuery:
`$.ajax({`. to `function ajax({`

What is mistaken in this script?

```
window.addEventListener("turbo:load", function() {
  let selectedDeviceId
  const codeReader = new ZXing.BrowserMultiFormatReader()
  console.log("ZXing code reader initialized")
  codeReader
    .getVideoInputDevices()
    .then(videoInputDevices => {
      const sourceSelect = document.getElementById("sourceSelect")
      selectedDeviceId = videoInputDevices[0].deviceId
      if (videoInputDevices.length >= 1) {
        videoInputDevices.forEach(element => {
          const sourceOption = document.createElement("option")
          sourceOption.text = element.label
          sourceOption.value = element.deviceId
          sourceSelect.appendChild(sourceOption)
        })

        sourceSelect.onchange = () => {
          selectedDeviceId = sourceSelect.value
        }

        const sourceSelectPanel = document.getElementById("sourceSelectPanel")
        sourceSelectPanel.style.display = "block"
      }

      document.getElementById("startButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
        codeReader.decodeFromVideoDevice(
          selectedDeviceId,
          "video",
          (result, err) => {
            if (result) {
              console.log(result)
              document.getElementById("result").textContent = result.text
              let formData = new FormData()
              let CodeParams = {
                code_data: result.text
              }
              formData.append("code_json_data", JSON.stringify(CodeParams))
              function ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:3000/articlephotos/barcode_section_update",
                type: "post",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
              })
            }
            if (err && !(err instanceof ZXing.NotFoundException)) {
              console.error(err)
              document.getElementById("result").textContent = err
            }
          }
        )
        console.log(
          `Started continous decode from camera with id ${selectedDeviceId}`
        )
      })

      document.getElementById("resetButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
        codeReader.reset()
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = ""
        console.log("Reset.")
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
    })
})
```

Comment: What is `function ajax({ url: "...", ... })` supposed to do? o.O

Comment: it is intended to send the result of the scan as an XHR posting

Comment: Right now its a syntax error...

Comment: I assumed as much, given the jQuery 'un'reliance.  That is why I posed the question.

Comment: `function ajax({...})` defined a function named ajax.. which you don't have a body for. This does not call the ajax function. You can use an AJAX library like Axios.

Comment: @PeterKrebs  yes that link might answer my question; I will investigate axios as I was not aware of it (my JS is -as is apparent- quite limited).  the `fetch()`. API always seems curious to me when the intention is to post

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer here for who comes around to it.

The suggestion from `@PeterKrebs` of using `axios` is pertinent.  Note however some syntaxic precisions, as [following the links](https://flaviocopes.com/axios/#post-requests) might leand one to use `axios.post` when `this.axios.post(...)` is necessary.

The script ends up very similar to the jQuery AJAX notation:

```
window.addEventListener("turbo:load", function() {
  let selectedDeviceId
  const codeReader = new ZXing.BrowserMultiFormatReader()
  console.log("ZXing code reader initialized")
  codeReader
    .getVideoInputDevices()
    .then(videoInputDevices => {
      const sourceSelect = document.getElementById("sourceSelect")
      selectedDeviceId = videoInputDevices[0].deviceId
      if (videoInputDevices.length >= 1) {
        videoInputDevices.forEach(element => {
          const sourceOption = document.createElement("option")
          sourceOption.text = element.label
          sourceOption.value = element.deviceId
          sourceSelect.appendChild(sourceOption)
        })

        sourceSelect.onchange = () => {
          selectedDeviceId = sourceSelect.value
        }

        const sourceSelectPanel = document.getElementById("sourceSelectPanel")
        sourceSelectPanel.style.display = "block"
      }

      document.getElementById("startButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
        codeReader.decodeFromVideoDevice(
          selectedDeviceId,
          "video",
          (result, err) => {
            if (result) {
              console.log(result)
              document.getElementById("result").textContent = result.text
              let formData = new FormData()
              let CodeParams = {
                code_data: result.text
              }
              formData.append("code_json_data", JSON.stringify(CodeParams))
              this.axios.post('<%= barcode_section_update_articlephotos_url %>', {
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
              })
            }
            if (err && !(err instanceof ZXing.NotFoundException)) {
              console.error(err)
              document.getElementById("result").textContent = err
            }
          }
        )
        console.log(
          `Started continous decode from camera with id ${selectedDeviceId}`
        )
      })

      document.getElementById("resetButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
        codeReader.reset()
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = ""
        console.log("Reset.")
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
    })
})
```